# THREE.JS cannot load mtl file

Tags: three.js, blender

It seems THREE.JS MTLLoader cannot load mtl file. It somehow take mtl file as JSON file, and tries to parse mtl file.

Here is the code:

```
var objLoader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
var mtlLoader = new THREE.MaterialLoader();



mtlLoader.load("istuff.mtl",function (materials) {
        materials.preload();
        objLoader.setMaterial(materials);
    objLoader.load("istuff.obj", function ( object ) {
        scene.add(object);
    }, onProgress, onError)
});
```

Here is the error:

```
VM64:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token # in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.onLoad (three.js:35569)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (three.js:30803)
```

## Blender MTL File: 'istuff.blend' //error here

Update:

[image]
Error:

```
GET http://localhost:63342/Users/yuqingyang/Downloads/imac%20(1)/mac_keyb.jpg 404 (Not Found)
```

It's trying to get image in my mac, but it's supposed to get the image from url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are using an instance of `ObjectLoader`. What you need is `OBJLoader`. Have a closer look at the following example:

https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_obj_mtl

Comment: Ahh, got it. Thank you.

Comment: But I got another problem, seems mtl file still doesn't loaded properly. I'd appreciate it if you can help me with that as well.

Comment: I guess you should open a new issue. It's not good if you post multiple questions at the same thread.